# Get No such file or directory in Visual Studio Code when Debug with gcc

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include

My C project need use MySQL, so there is code:
#include "mysql.h"

I just couldn't find out where should I add include path, or which key point I missed, I think I have get it done already. When I debug with (Windows)启动, it's works fine. But when I choose "gcc.exe", it always get "mysql.h: no such file or directory", please help!
I tried everything I can but still get this error.

[image]

this is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

this is my launch.json:

```
{
    // 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 
    // 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
    // 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - 生成和调试活动文件",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        },
        {
            ....................
        },
    ]
}
```

this is my task.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I",
                "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/include",
                "-L",
                "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/lib",
                "-llibmysql",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe\""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try is hiding those spaces in your paths; terminal will read them as the end of an argument and start of a new one.

For example, in your launch.json, you have

> "options": {
> "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw64\\bin"
> },

which I would try editing to

> "options": {
> "cwd": "C:\\\"Program Files\"\\mingw64\\bin"
> },

Currently, terminal sees the path "C:\Program" and interprets "Files\mingw64\bin" as some weird argument that it probably just ignores. Your windows debugger may be smart enough to figure out that's wrong, but terminal operates pretty literally.

With "Program Files" contained in quotes (with escape chars), terminal should be able to read the whole path. Try that everywhere you have spaces in your paths and see if it helps.